# Prove that Energy Function is constant over time

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $B$ be an area with smooth boundary, $U$ and open superset of $B$.

Let  $F:(p,t) \in U \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto F(p,t) \in \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is two times continuously differentiable in the three variables $p = (x,y,z)$ und a time variable $t$.

We define $\Delta _p F = \partial_x ^2 F + \partial_y ^2 F + \partial_z ^2 F$

Lets assume $F$ meets all the criteria for the wave equation:

1. $\partial_t^2F (p,t) = \Delta_p F(p,t) $ for all $(p,t)\in B \times\mathbb{R}$
2. $F(p,t) = 0$ for all  $(p,t)\in \partial B \times\mathbb{R}$

Show that the energy function $E:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $$E(t) = \int_{B}((\partial_t F(p,t))^2 +(\partial_x F(p,t))^2+(\partial_y F(p,t))^2+(\partial_z F(p,t))^2)dvol(p)$$
is constant for $t\in \mathbb{R}$

The hints given to solve this problem are:

either assume that $B=Q$ is a cuboid or use (without proving it) [multidimensional differentiation under the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

**How I tried solving this**

If $E(t)$ is constant over time we know $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = 0$
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_{B}((\partial_t F(p,t))^2 +(\partial_x F(p,t))^2+(\partial_y F(p,t))^2+(\partial_z F(p,t))^2)dvol(p)\\ =  \int_{B}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(((\partial_t F(p,t))^2 +(\partial_x F(p,t))^2+(\partial_y F(p,t))^2+(\partial_z F(p,t))^2) \right)dvol(p)$$

Since all points in the intergral are in $B$ we can use the fact $\partial_tF (p,t) = \Delta_p F(p,t) $ for all $(p,t)\in B \times\mathbb{R}$ from above giving me 
$$\int_{B}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(((\partial_x ^2 F + \partial_y ^2 F + \partial_z ^2 F)^2 +(\partial_x F)^2+(\partial_y F)^2+(\partial_z F)^2) \right)dvol(p)$$

Somehow I must show that this is equals to $0$
I am pretty lost so I really appreciate your help.

Since $B$ has a smooth boundary and the hint tells me to look at $B$ as a cuboid I assume on can use Stokes Theorem or Gauss Theorem to solve this.

Comment: If a function is constant for some variable, what does it mean for that be the case, Say, f'(t)=0.  If not is defined over it's domain, and the mixed partials are equal, then you have a potential field. These are things you know, but perhaps reiterating them will help.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how one tackles such a problem, since I am completely lost.